# Time estimate for ABAP development

Tags: abap, estimation

I'm looking for a table or list of standard time estimations for developments in ABAP, something customizable in some variables according to the development team, complexity of project, etc...

Something similar to:

```
Simple Module Pool -> 10 hours
Complex Module Pool -> 30 hours
Definition of Dictionary -> (0,4 * number_of_tables * average_fields ) hours
ALV Report -> (2 * number_of_parameters) hours
```

I've searched but haven't found anything yet. I found AboveSoft Adaptive Estimator, what looks like a software tool to do what I need, but I prefer something... manual, an official or standard table.

Do you know anything like that?

Thank you in advance.

Updated, as requested in comments by Rob S., to provide more information for future similar questions:

What I'm looking for is a bunch of formulas, any metric system that can be applicable to (or even created for) time estimations on SAP development.

I'm looking for a technic/tool/method to estimate SAP work, duration, cost, something similar to COCOMO II, FP, ESTIMACS or SLIM for SAP development.

Comment: added estimation tag; this thread may serve as a good counter-example for the next carpenter sent out to find a board-stretcher

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I am reading this right, you are looking for a something to estimate how long it would take someone to program an application. I would doubt an official table actually exists.

Development time is highly variable. Programmer experience, complexity of requirements, clarity of requirements, and dozens of other factors affect how much time development takes. So even if an official table exists, it may not be accurate.

Answer (score 9):

the formulas you made up for illustration purposes in your question are as good as any others - in other words, you are asking for something that is pointless.

the reason is that no formula can account for the truly important variables:

- your team
- your customer
- your environment
- your standards and best practices

all of which will have a much larger drag coefficient than any other terms

if you want accurate estimates, *ask your developers, and track their accuracy*

if you truly think that this sort of thing can be reduced to formulas, **please resign as a project manager immediately**

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a project manager, I'm only an internship into a SAP team. Due to my experience in other languages I DO know that there are so many variables that it's impossible to automate a estimation of development time.

But I've received the work of search for a "standard table of estimated times" for SAP/ABAP developments and, being a newbie in SAP, I imagined that will could exist any metric standarization.

I think i've suffer a rough joke from my manager...

Sorry for the inconvenience of my question.

Comment: lol - email your manager this thread and tell him the SO community thinks he should resign for the good of the team

Comment: Its actually not all that uncommon for project managers to seriously believe that you can put a timetable on things like this...flawed...yes...but not uncommon.

Comment: it's not uncommon for project managers (et al!) to seriously believe that all programmers are interchangable also, but that doesn't make it true or useful ;-)

Comment: Don't worry about the inconvenience. :) It was a well written question. We can hope that the next person to ask the question will see this thread.

Comment: Thank you for your support. And yes, this thread is going to my manager's inbox... and hope it'll do to other people manager's inbox in the future ;)

Answer (score 1):

Let me guess... you're a project manager?

There is no "one way" in programming, especially not in the highly specialized world of ABAP.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Excel, Numbers, Gant charts, to do it manualy but you won't be able to find **ANY** automated thing for that, you'll have to do it yourself!

Answer (score 1):

HI, I understand your need...
I'm project manager and estimation specialist, and what you're looking for is a table for estimate effort, por develop ABAP components...
You need a tabulate table, where based on complexity of the component and complexity of the change, yo can get an estimate effort. (this is based in one estimation method called Object Points http://yunus.hacettepe.edu.tr/~sencer/objectp.html)

This effor is only for Codding & Unit Testing, you as project manager (or your project manager!) must to take this estimation as input, but you need to estimate another project factors to get the complete "project estimation"...

I didn't find this table, or some estandar table for bencharmak, so I'm working in a project withing my software factory to build our own table...

I hope this will be helpful for you..
Regards,

Answer (score 1):

this simply doesn't exist. General metrics are so general that are useless. Project Managers should find other ways to make their life easier, like resign, but not try to quantify developments as if peeling potatoes.

Answer (score 1):

Try AboveSoft's new tool, named AboveSoft Predictor. You can download it here www.abovesoft.com

It connects to an SAP system and you can easily (graphically) generate your own estimation templates which are saved in SAP.

Dave.